# Removal of records with duplicate values in certain columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have following table STG with 2 million records -

```
STG(ACCT_NUM,NAME,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE)
```

I added column `SSN nvarchar(255) NULL`  and re-inserted 2 million records. Now I want to delete the ***duplicate*** records which *doe not* have any value in SSN but other column values are matching since SSN is being inserted as null for some records.

I want to delete those duplicate records where all other column values are matching but SSN is not. There are some unique records with null SSN. I do not want them to be deleted.

Comment: Please tell me your SSN column is NOT social security numbers. And if they are, please tell me they are encrypted. You should NOT store SSN unless you actually need to. Do yourself and your company a favor and get them encrypted immediately if not sooner. This data is very sensitive and not encrypting it is irresponsible and dangerous for your company.

Comment: @SeanLange - Thanks Sean, but it is not social security number. Thanks anyway!

Comment: LOL yet another reason to use meaningful names instead of abbreviations. :)

Comment: You have edited the question but there is conflicting information. First you say you want to delete rows with no SSN but then you you say you to keep some of them. What are the rules here?

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need to delete records with a NULL value for SSN.

```
DELETE FROM STG
WHERE SSN IS NULL;
```

Edit:

Here is a MySQL solution for what you're trying to do given the comment below:

```
DELETE FROM STG
    WHERE SSN IS NULL
    AND (ACCT_NUM, NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE)
    IN (SELECT ACCT_NUM, NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM STG) AS STG1 WHERE SSN IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of guessing here since the information is not complete and the requirements are  conflicting currently.

```
with MyDeleteCTE as
(
    SELECT 
        ACCT_NUM
        ,NAME
        ,ADDRESS
        ,CITY
        ,STATE
    FROM STG s1
    left join STG s2 on 
        s1.ACCT_NUM = s2.ACCT_NUM
        and s1.NAME = s2.NAME
        and s1.ADDRESS = s2.ADDRESS
        and s1.CITY = s2.CITY
        and s1.STATE = s2.STATE
        and s1.SSN <> s2.SSN
)

delete MyDeleteCTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE s1
    FROM STG s1
    INNER JOIN STG s2 on 
        s1.ACCT_NUM = s2.ACCT_NUM
        and s1.NAME = s2.NAME
        and s1.ADDRESS = s2.ADDRESS
        and s1.STATE = s2.STATE
        and s1.CITY = s2.CITY
        and s1.SSN <> s2.SSN
        and (isnull(s1.SSN,'')='' OR s1.SSN is null)
```